# Stacked barplot for table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a table which lists different categories and some related subcategories. Something like:

| General Type | Specific Food |
| --- | --- |
| fruit | apple |
| fruit | apple |
| meat | ham |
| fruit | banana |
| meat | pork |
| vegetable | lettuce |

Now I want to display this in a stacked barplot where each ***General Type*** has its own bar. Each of those bars should be subdivided into its subcategories (in this case ***Specific Food***).

In the end there will be three bars (***fruit***, ***meat*** and ***vegetable***). Where ***fruit*** has a height of three with two different areas (of size two for ***apple*** and one for ***banana***) and so on, I think you get the Idea.... Or you just look at the Picture I uploaded:

[image: Basic Idea of what the Plot should look like].

I hope there is an easy way I just didn't find...

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn's [`countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html) can do the counting and automatically create an appropriate legend.  Unfortunately, this either puts the bars next to each other (default `dodge=True`), or puts them on top of each other starting from `y=0` (`dodge=False`). An idea is to loop through the generated bars and stack them via changing their y-position.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['fruit', 'apple'],
        ['fruit', 'apple'],
        ['meat', 'ham'],
        ['fruit', 'banana'],
        ['meat', 'pork'],
        ['vegetable', 'lettuce']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['General', 'Specific'])
# df_grp = df.groupby(['General', 'Specific']).agg(len).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Count'})

ax = sns.countplot(data=df, x='General', hue='Specific', dodge=False)
bottoms = {}
for container in ax.containers:
    for bar in container:
        h = bar.get_height()
        if not np.isnan(h) and h > 0:
            x = bar.get_x()
            w = bar.get_width()
            if x in bottoms:
                bar.set_y(bottoms[x])
                bottoms[x] += h
            else:
                bottoms[x] = h
            ax.text(x + w / 2, bottoms[x] - h / 2, f'{h:.0f}', ha='center', va='center')
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale() # recalculates the ylims due to the changed bars
ax.yaxis.major.locator.set_params(integer=True)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: stacked countplot]